# How do I use hook_nodeapi()?

Tags: 6, hooks

I found an example on the Internet: [Transform CCK field to body content](http://www.zimplicit.se/knowledge/drupal-hooknodeapi-example-transform-cck-field-body-content).

```
function riddle_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser, $page) {
  if ($node->type == "historia") {
    switch ($op) {
      case 'view':
        if ($node->field_svar[0]['value'] != "" AND $page == 1) {
          $svar = '<form><fieldset class="collapsible collapsed">
            <legend>Svar</legend>
            <div>'.$node->field_svar[0]['value'].'</div>
            </fieldset></form>';

          $node->content['riddle'] = array(
            '#value' => $svar,
            '#weight' => 0,
          );

          if (is_array($node->content['field_svar'])) {
            unset($node->content['field_svar']);
          }
        }

        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know what the purpose of the following code is. Why should I use it?

```
 if (is_array($node->content['field_svar'])) {
   unset($node->content['field_svar']);
 }
```

What's the use of the `hook_nodeapi()` arguments `$a3` and `a4`?
If in the case of a view operation, I set the $a3 to true or 1, will the body only effect on the node teaser? Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code is used because the module is already rendering the CCK field, and wants to avoid that Drupal renders the content of that field.

```
if (is_array($node->content['field_svar'])) {
  unset($node->content['field_svar']);
}
```

Without using that code, the field content will appear twice: once inside a field set, and once outside that field set.

The last parameters used for `hook_nodeapi()` are described from the documentation as:

> $a3
>
> - For "view", passes in the $teaser parameter from node_view().
> - For "validate", passes in the $form parameter from node_validate().
>
> $a4
>
> - For "view", passes in the $page parameter from node_view().

It means that, when the operation is "view," `$a3` is `TRUE` when Drupal is displaying the teaser (and `FALSE` when Drupal is displaying the full node content), and `$a4` is TRUE when the node is being displayed alone in a page (and `FALSE` when the node is being displayed together other nodes in the same page).
To understand the meaning of the different values given to `$a4`, `$a4` is `TRUE` when Drupal is displaying, for example, the page http://example.com/node/1 (where the same page displays only a node); its value is `FALSE` when Drupal is visualizing the front page and there are more than one node promoted to the front page.

Comment: thank you very much. your explaination make me know a lot.